# POJO have null values when converting with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have tried to look for an answer on this but realized there are multiple similar but none matches this one.

I have a JSON object with this structure

```
{
  "model": {
     "serie" : "123456",
      "id" : "abc123"
    /// many fields
  },
  "externalModel": {
    "serie" : "123456",
    "fieldX" : "abcde"
   // many fields as well
}
```

and I'm doing this at my code:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 MyObject object = mapper.readValue(hit.getSourceAsString(), MyObject.class);
```

where MyObject has this form:

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

public class MyObject {


    @JsonProperty("serie")
    String serie;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    Long id;

    MyObject() {}
   }
```

When I convert I don't get any exception, but rather I get myObject with all values set to **null**

I have no idea what could be wrong since no exception returned, any idea?

Comment: "serie" and "id ist nested into "model" in your json but not in your object

Comment: They don't match. Your json has 2 objects model and externalModel, but you are trying to map it to MyObject which has serie and id.

Comment: `MyObject` does not match the structure of the whole json

Comment: is there any way to ignore the parents?

Comment: I tried to use root, like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145728/convert-jackson-to-object-using-withroot-in-a-multiple-roots-model but no success, any idea how to do this mapping?

Comment: Not sure if [`@JsonUnwrapped`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonUnwrapped.html) would do the trick here.

Comment: @jpganz18 jackson isn't trying to let you do anything you want. Jackson assumes you make your JSON and your classes so that they're modeled the same way. If they aren't, it won't help you. The only way to "do this mapping" is to force converters down its throats that would be much more complicated to figure out than would be just using a simple JSON parsing library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use root property `model`,

You can rename `MyObject` to `MyModel` and create a `MyObject`

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyObject{
    @JsonProperty("model")
    MyModel model;
}
```

and then check `model`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need two objects in MyObject.

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyModel {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("serie")
    private String serie;

   //Generate getters and setters of these two

}

@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ExternalObject {

    @JsonProperty("serie")
    private String serie;

    @JsonProperty("fieldX")
    private String fieldX;

   //Generate getters and setters of these two
}

@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyObject{

    @JsonProperty("model")
    private MyModel model;

    @JsonProperty("externalModel")
    private ExternalObject externalModel;

   //Generate getters and setters of these two  
}
```

Now when you use it like below, it will work fine.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyObject object = mapper.readValue(hit.getSourceAsString(), MyObject.class);
```